# Missing character in javascript regexp capture because of sharp (#) character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

In the expression: `/^(C|Db|D|Eb|E|F|F#|G|Ab|A|Bb|B)(.*)$/`, `Cm7` will have two captured groups: `C` and `m7`. `Eb-^9` will have the capture groups `Eb` and `-^9`.

Why is it then that `F#maj7` gets captured as `F` and `#maj7` instead of `F#` and `maj7`? I tried escaping the sharp character to no avail. `String.prototype.match` and `String.prototype.split` both give the same result, as well as [regexr itself](http://regexr.com/3gdic)

Is this a bug in the regexp engine?

Comment: A better idea is to use `?` quantifier matching 1 or 0 occurrences and character classes - `/^([CG]|Db?|Eb?|F#?|Ab?|Bb?)(.*)$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by switching `F` and `F#` because the order meant it was looking for `F` before `F#`.

This seems to work for me now:

```
/^(C|Db|D|Eb|E|F#|F|G|Ab|A|Bb|B)(.*)$/
```

Here is the [example](https://regex101.com/r/IHvW8k/1).